# Styling a Command Link as Command Button

Tags: visualforce, css

I'm trying to style a command link as a command button and I have the code for this,

```
<apex:commandlink value="Add new Contact" action="{!editNewCont}" styleclass="btn MyBtn">
```

and my CSS goes like this,

```
.MyBtn{text-decoration:none;padding:4px;}
```

But for some reason the MyBtn properties (padding is not applied correctly). How do I do this? Also, is there way I could give the "btn" property as part of the CSS so that my styleclass would be like this,

```
styleclass="MyBtn" instead of styleclass="btn MyBtn"
```

Please advise.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use an `<apex:commandButton>`?

Comment: Mark, I'm not able to use Command button since I have to pass an apex:parm and it doesn't like apex:commandButtons

Comment: If you don't get your CSS inheritance issue squared away, there's some well-known workarounds to allow you to use the `<apex:param>` tag with a command button. https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000002664

Comment: Mark, that did it. Thanks for sharing this workaround. Is there a way to flag your comment as the 'answer', that would help others like me.

Comment: Hey @JJSHHS  have you tried with **.MyBtn{text-decoration:none;padding:4px !important ;}**

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you why the padding isn't being applied without seeing your page, but I suggest that you check to see whether the styling is being overridden by another element; you can do this using the [Developer Console](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/elements-styles).

With regard to your second point, you would need to copy the definition for btn into MyBtn - but if btn is a Salesforce-defined class, this is not a good idea (as your copy may become outdated with future updates to Salesforce).

Comment: I believe the default salesforce style btn overrides the MyBtn styling. Is there anyway to prevent that?

Comment: JJSHHS, you'll need to change the MyBtn styling to take precedence over the .btn styling.  You can use CSS specificity to do this.  See http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `!important` next to your padding attribute, like `padding: 4px !important;`, in your CSS tag.

If it doesn't work, then why not just use the `style` attribute of the commandLink? You can put the padding in there too (but it will only be applied to that specific link).